# Аудиофайл в виде аудиопотока

Tags: веб-программирование, аудио

Нужно представить содержимое аудиофайла в виде потока с микрофона или веб-камеры. Чтобы скайп, любое другое приложение, которое умеет работать с аудио с микрофона/веб-камеры определяло новое устройство и могло использовать его в качестве источника, а на самом деле туда должно подавать содержимое аудиофайла.
Возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял то вам необходимо транслировать аудио запись к примеру в Skype, для этого просто необходимо в настройках приложения выбрать другой источник (не микрофон а стерео микшер )звука, и начать воспроизводить на ПК необходимый звуковой файл.

а вообще вам [сюда](http://user.hashcode.ru/) надо.